# SharePoint CSOM Item not found (checked out element)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom, item-checkedin

Code executes from an Azure Hosted app (authentication via app-only context):

`var item = changeList.GetItemById(75);`

Element with id 75 exists but it is checked out.

Get the Exception "Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user"

I assume this is related to the permission levels of the SP app, I have given it Site Collection - FullControl and still the problem arises.

Is there any way to work around this without going with a service account?

Comment: Is there at least one checked-in version of the item you are trying to retrieve ? Are you using app-only context to get this item ?

Comment: Yes , no issues with checked in items... and yes, app-only context.